# using "the" when referring to languages

Tags: articles, proper-nouns

When should one use "the" when referring to a language and when is just the noun appropriate?

e.g. At the end of a quote one may see "Translated from the German." 
What about, "Joe translated the article from [the?] German."?

But we would also say: "Mike is fluent in Mandarin" not "Joe is fluent in *the* Mandarin".

Comment: Related:http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7788/definite-article-before-name-of-languages

Comment: The definite article in front of "German" here has nothing to do with the German language. "The German" is short for "the version written in German" -- the article belongs to the document (book, paper, journal ...). ... ...

Comment: ... On the other hand, I've used *the* before "German" in the above sentence ("the German language") because 'German' is an adjective for 'language' there, and the article applies to the noun 'language.'

Comment: @jos That post may add to the confusion, it deals with only one case. (I'll read the full post & revert, though.)

Comment: Kris, IMHO you have written the answer. Why not make it one formally?

Answer (score 1):

The word *the* in this context is referring to the translation itself, not the language.

Using your example above, clarity can be provided by adding one word *Translated from the German* ***version***

Comment: There are cases where the definite article is used before language names that don’t refer to versions or translations, though. The ones I’ve encountered the most are the Gaelic languages of Scottish and, particularly, Irish: many Irish people would quite naturally say something like, “I wouldn’t know how to say that in the Gaelic”. And of course if the language is further modified in various ways, the definite article is mandatorily added just like before any other proper nouns: “the English of our times”, “the German spoken in 1665”, “the Spanish I learnt at school”, etc.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that is interesting, though I have never heard someone use the in the Gaelic example that you gave, though the others that I have

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David Watts, and would like to add the following.

The word ***the*** would also refer not just to a translated version, but to any work in that language as well as in some cases (as Kris mentioned via comment) the language itself.

> Translated from *the German.*

This would refer to the German book, the German version, the German text, etc.

> I speak *German*

This refers to the language itself

However, one may also use the article when referring to an instance of the language in an instance like this:

> *The German* I know isn't very useful.

Take care when using 'the German' since it may seem to a listener as if you are referring to a certain German person